# Swift: An appstore like app using scrollview

Tags: swift, app-store

I am trying to figure out how to make/design an app that navigates similar to the appstore where the first row is a set of pictures you swipe horizontally then you have like a list of table value. How would i go about doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

You would use a `Container View` with a `UICollectionViewController`, a `UITableViewController` or implement your own custom `UIScrollView`